# Pegar apenas os ultimos links de um sitemap

Tags: c#, wordpress, sitemap

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using JoeBlogs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ReaderXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var website = LeitorDeXML("http://SITE ORIGEM/").ToArray();
            var total = website.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i < total; i++)
            {
                Postagem(website[i]);
            }
        }
        private static IEnumerable<string> LeitorDeXML(string url)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Carregando " + string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));

            XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));
            XElement element = XElement.Load(string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));

            XName urlNodes = XName.Get("url", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
            XName locNodes = XName.Get("loc", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

            List<string> resultado = new List<string>();

            // Pega os últimos 10 elementos da lista
            List<XElement> lista = Enumerable.Reverse(element.Elements(urlNodes)).Take(10).Reverse().ToList();

            foreach (XElement e in lista)
            {
                var postUrl = e.Element(locNodes).Value;
                resultado.Add(postUrl);
            }

            return resultado;
        }
        private static void Postagem(string website)
        {
            try
            {
                //LINK,USER,SENHA WP
                string link = "http://SITE NOVO";
                string username = "user wp";
                string password = "senha wp";

                //Leitura do HTML
                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument resultat = web.Load(website);

                //Separar TITULO e CONTEUDO
                string titulopost = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-title')]")[0].InnerHtml;
                string conteudo = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-content')]")[0].InnerHtml; //ERRO AQUI

                //Entrada no wp
                var wp = new WordPressWrapper(link + "/xmlrpc.php", username, password);
                var post = new Post();

                //Categoria -- Não está funcionando ainda a parte da criação da categoria

                int website_corpo = 25;
                string categoria = website.Substring(website_corpo);
                int indexof_barra = categoria.IndexOf("/");
                int comeco_cat = 0;
                string categoria_f = categoria.Substring(comeco_cat, indexof_barra);

                //Data

                post.DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(0);

                //Postagem
                post.Title = titulopost;
                post.Body = conteudo;

                wp.NewPost(post, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Não passa da linha 63...

```
Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: Eu tenho um laço for:

var website = LeitorDeXML("http://LINK DO SITE PARA LER SITEMAP/").ToArray();
            var total = website.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i < total; i++)
            {
                Postagem(website[i]);
            }

o método LeitorDeXML é o método que vai ler o Sitemap...
o método Postagem não sei se é relevante...
Daria para modificar o FOR que ja tenho ?

Comment: Faz um for de trás pra frente aqui nessa linha. foreach (XElement e in list)
    {

Comment: Como seria este FOR?

Comment: foreach (XElement e in list)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < list.count; i--;) {
                var postUrl = e.Element(locNodes).Value;
                countPost++;
                urls.Add(postUrl);
                }
            }

Isto? Pois se for isto está dando erro...

Comment: Me desculpe, mas como manda uma mensagem pelo bate-papo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isto seria usar o método [`Enumerable.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) para inverter a lista, e com o [`Enumerable.Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) obter *n* elementos:

```
List<XElement> lista = Enumerable.Reverse(element.Elements(urlNodes)).Take(10).Reverse().ToList();
```

A tua função deve ficar assim:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> LeitorDeXML(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Carregando " + string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));

    XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));
    XElement element = XElement.Load(string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));

    XName urlNodes = XName.Get("url", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    XName locNodes = XName.Get("loc", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

    List<string> resultado = new List<string>();

    // Pega os últimos 10 elementos da lista
    List<XElement> lista = Enumerable.Reverse(element.Elements(urlNodes)).Take(10).Reverse().ToList();

    foreach (XElement e in lista)
    {
        var postUrl = e.Element(locNodes).Value;
        resultado.Add(postUrl);
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: continuo com a var countPost = 1;?

Comment: @RaulCorreia Não precisa dele, pois você só pega os últimos 10 elementos.

Comment: eu ia postar um for de trás para frente que não vejo como sendo uma boa solução. + 1

Comment: Deu alguns erros ;x

Comment: Error 2 A local variable named 'url' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'url', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Error 3 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: @RaulCorreia Já corrigi, veja se funciona para você agora.

Comment: Estou tentando transferir os posts de um site para outro, um é meu e o outro também rs... A maneira mais facil que achei seria pelo sitemap, pois o outro não tenho acesso algum... tenho o seguinte código no total: (vou postar na resposta) Ele está dando erro na linha 63, ele não está conseguindo passar de la...

Comment: @RaulCorreia Mas o problema inicial, pegar os 10 últimos items, está **OK**? eu testei aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Ele consegue pegar... Não consegue passar para o outro método para a separação de CONTEUDO e TITULO e depois postar...

Comment: @RaulCorreia Bom, se possível positive e marque a resposta como aceita. =) Esse **outro problema** é com *xPath*, que é um assunto diferente, se possível crie uma nova pergunta, posso tentar ajudar lá. Obrigado.

Comment: ok, obrigado a todos =)

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser retornar os 10 últimos, mas não de trás para frente, pode criar um método de extensão:

```
namespace Extensoes 
{
    public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
        {
            return source.Skip(Math.Max(0, source.Count() - n));
        }
    }
}
```

E então utilizar assim:

```
using Extensoes;

private static IEnumerable<string> LeitorDeXML(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Carregando " + string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));
    XElement element = XElement.Load(string.Format("{0}sitemap.xml", url));

    XName urlNodes = XName.Get("url", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    XName locNodes = XName.Get("loc", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

    return element.Elements(urlNodes).TakeLast(10).Select(x => x.Element(locNodes).Value);
}
```